# trying to get text from html via xpath with scrapy "Mobilya"

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

Below is the HTML, I am working on and I am trying to get "Gardroplar" text but it return me empty

start with `<ol class="nav align-items-center flex-nowrap text-nowrap overflow-auto hide-scrollbar>`

```
<li>
  <a href="/">
    <svg class="icon-home m-0">
      <use
        xlink:href="/_ui/responsive/theme-alpha/images/icons.svg#icon-home"
      ></use>
    </svg>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <svg class="icon-arrow2 m-0">
    <use
      xlink:href="/_ui/responsive/theme-alpha/images/icons.svg#icon-arrow1"
    ></use>
  </svg>
  <a href="/mobilya/c/109">Mobilya</a>
</li>
<li>
  <svg class="icon-arrow1 m-0">
    <use
      xlink:href="/_ui/responsive/theme-alpha/images/icons.svg#icon-arrow1"
    ></use>
  </svg>
  <span class="top-breadcrumb">
    <a
      class="d-inline-flex align-items-center border pl-10 rounded-sm"
      href="/mobilya/gardiroplar/c/109011"
      data-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-expanded="false"
      >Gardıroplar<svg class="icon-arrow7 m-0 rotate-top">
        <use
          xlink:href="/_ui/responsive/theme-alpha/images/icons.svg#icon-arrow7"
        ></use>
      </svg>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu px-15 py-0 border-0 text-c2">
      <li class="border-bottom py-10">
        <a
          class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between pl-5 py-5 reverse font-weight-bold"
          href="/mobilya/gardiroplar/c/109011"
          >Gardıroplar</a
        >
      </li>

      <li class="px-10 border-bottom">
        <a
          class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between pl-5 py-5 reverse"
          href="/gardiroplar/kapakli-gardiroplar/c/109011002"
          >Kapaklı Gardıroplar<svg class="icon-arrow1 ml-5">
            <use
              xlink:href="/_ui/responsive/theme-alpha/images/icons.svg#icon-arrow1"
            ></use>
          </svg>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="px-10 border-bottom">
        <a
          class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between pl-5 py-5 reverse"
          href="/gardiroplar/surgulu-gardiroplar/c/109011003"
          >Sürgülü Gardıroplar<svg class="icon-arrow1 ml-5">
            <use
              xlink:href="/_ui/responsive/theme-alpha/images/icons.svg#icon-arrow1"
            ></use>
          </svg>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="px-10 border-bottom">
        <a
          class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between pl-5 py-5 reverse"
          href="/gardiroplar/bez-dolaplar/c/109011001"
          >Bez Dolaplar<svg class="icon-arrow1 ml-5">
            <use
              xlink:href="/_ui/responsive/theme-alpha/images/icons.svg#icon-arrow1"
            ></use>
          </svg>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </span>
</li>
<li>
  <svg class="icon-arrow1 m-0">
    <use
      xlink:href="/_ui/responsive/theme-alpha/images/icons.svg#icon-arrow1"
    ></use>
  </svg>
  <a href="/gardiroplar/kapakli-gardiroplar/c/109011002">Kapaklı Gardıroplar</a>
</li>
</ol>
```

My code:

```
response.xpath('//ol[@class="nav.align-items-center.flex-nowrap.text-nowrap.overflow-auto.hide-scrollbar.tab-title"]//li[svg[contains(@class,"icon-arrow2")]]/text()').getall()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case `icon-arrow2` class is fixed value there you can use the following XPath:

```py
"//li[./*[contains(@class,'icon-arrow2')]]//a"
```

The complete command is

```py
response.xpath("//li[./*[contains(@class,'icon-arrow2')]]//a/text()").getall()
```

**UPD**
After you shared the actual link to that page I can give you better locator.
This will work:

```py
response.xpath("//li[./*[contains(@class,'icon-arrow')]]/a[contains(@href,'mob')]/text()").getall()
```

**UPD2**
This will give you `Kapaklı Gardıroplar` text:

```py
response.xpath("//li[./*[contains(@class,'icon-arrow')]]/a[contains(@href,'gar')]/text()").getall()
```

**UPD3**
This will give you `Gardıroplar` text as you defined:

```py
response.xpath("//li[@class='border-bottom py-10']/a/text()").getall()
```

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to explain their mistakes. +1

Comment: I see. Thanks. I see no cause to apologize. +1

Comment: It returns me an empty. You may see the link https://www.koctas.com.tr/minar-mobilya-membran-402-gardirop-52x160x186-cm/p/1000464829

Comment: Well.. That's because you didn't share a link to that page. Now I can give you better locator. See the updated answer

Comment: thank you for your  help but it returns me ['Mobilya', 'Kapaklı Gardıroplar'] not ['Gardroplar']

Comment: You asked for `Mobilya`. this is what I see from the title of this question

Comment: You are totally right, i noticed that i give this information begining of question, I'll be glad, if you help me

Comment: So what exactly do you want to get?

Comment: thank you very much i am trying to get ['Gardroplar']

Comment: It returns ['Kapaklı Gardıroplar'] but i need ['Gardroplar']

Comment: The only element seems to be similar to what you pasted in shared HTML is that. It contains `Kapaklı Gardıroplar` text

Comment: It is as on above   <li class="border-bottom py-10">
        <a
          class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between pl-5 py-5 reverse font-weight-bold"
          href="/mobilya/gardiroplar/c/109011"
          >Gardıroplar</a
        >
      </li>

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are facing is you're using a `css` selector in an `xpath` statement.  Assuming your path is accurate you would need to use the full text of the class.

```
response.xpath('//ol[@class="nav align-items-center flex-nowrap text-nowrap overflow-auto hide-scrollbar tab-title"]//li[svg[contains(@class,"icon-arrow2")]]/text()').getall()
```

BTW Prophets answer is the way to go, I just wanted to explain what your code is missing.